# Prevent synchronization of identity column when inserting with EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework-4

Using EF4 /w SQL Server 2008.

The following code (against a table with a PK, defined as `Int IDENTITY(1,1)`:

```
ctx.AddObject(GetEntitySetName(), newEntity);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

The results when profiling SQL are the insert statement following by a lookup against the table I'm inserting into:

```
SELECT ID FROM Table
WHERE ID = @@ScopeIdentity AND @@RowCount > 0
```

Is there a way to prevent `EntityFramework` from retreiving the `Identity` seed?  I don't need the ID back in my .Net code and under high volume situations it seems like a wasted operation.

Altenatively, is there a way to tell EF to change the way it performs this operation?  The strategy used goes against recommendations made by Microsoft in this defect report:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=328811

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change this behavior when using database generated keys (properties marked with `StorgeGeneratedPattern.Identity`). EF needs a real key value for inserted entity so the only way to avoid the query is to not using database generated keys at all and handling it yourselves in the application.